# Google App Engine python - Self is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a request that maps to this class ChatMsg
It takes in 3 get variables, username, roomname, and msg. But it fails on this last line here.

```
class ChatMsg(webapp.RequestHandler): # this is line 239
    def get(self):
        username = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('username'))
        roomname = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('roomname')) # this is line 242
```

When it tries to assign roomname, it tells me:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'self' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/chatboxes/1.341998073649951735/chatroom.py", line 239, in <module>
    class ChatMsg(webapp.RequestHandler):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/chatboxes/1.341998073649951735/chatroom.py", line 242, in ChatMsg
    roomname = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('roomname'))
```

what the hell is going on to make self not defined

Comment: The code looks OK to me at a glance, are you sure this isn't a synchronization problem with the server or something? Judging by the file path you're not running this locally.

Comment: Unless there is some metaclass magic the code looks ok as is. What is `type(ChatMsg)`?

Comment: Triple-check your indentation. Indentation differences are very significant in Python. Make sure that you don't have mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: i agree with @Matti & @J.F... the code looks good as-is. however, you may have had a typo in your code that you fixed locally but haven't uploaded to Google yet. is the code you pasted actually running on the server?

Comment: Hmmmmm ... I've never seen a `class` statement in a traceback before; how does that happen??? It's purporting to show that the `class` statement is calling the `roomname = ...` statement. Please show a few lines BEFORE that `class` statement.

Comment: Is the **whole** code that's giving you this crazy-looking problem readable anywhere, in exactly the version where it's giving you the problem?  Indentation issues, showing a different code than the version you've uploaded, etc, are all possibilities, but this exact failure in this exact code is **not**, no matter what "metaclass magic" might be in play.

Answer (score 3):

This should be an indentation problem. The traceback shows that the error is not in the get() method. You get the NameError exception at the time of the definition of your class.
Try to execute the following code, you will get the same exception as you've got.

```
class ChatMsg(object): # this is line 239
    def get(self):
        username = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('username'))
    roomname = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('roomname')) # this is line 242
```